# What is the best way to drop alignment artifacts in sequence objects in biopython?

Tags: python, seqio

I have a bunch of sequences created with `Roary` which I want to preprocess. When I read the sequences (genomics data) I want to translate them to protein sequences using:

```
import pandas as pd
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO

def read_fasta_file(fn):
    with open(fn,'r') as file:
        fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta')
        sequences = pd.DataFrame([{
            'filename': basename(fn),
            'id': rec.id,
            'seq': str(rec.seq.translate())} for rec in fasta_sequences])
    return sequences
```

The problem is that `.translate()` fails with:

> TranslationError: Codon 'T--' is invalid

Is there a build-in function to ignore the dashes?

Comment: That is some cool comprehension within a dataframe ... of course you need `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 2):

I think the `.ungap()` is what I was looking for.

```
def read_fasta_file(fn):
    with open(fn,'r') as file:
        fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(file, 'fasta')
        sequences = pd.DataFrame([{
            'filename': basename(fn),
            'id': rec.id,
            'seq': str(rec.seq.ungap().translate())} for rec in fasta_sequences])
    return sequences
```